# Setting class variable in Controller Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller class

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

    def firstMethod
       @obj = #get friends list from FB
    end

    def secondMethod
     puts @obj
    end
end
```

So in /my/firstMethod , i have

```
  <%= link_to "Likes","/my/secondMethod" %>
```

The method is called and page is rendered but "puts @obj" display blank.

I know one way is to use **before_filter** but since its a expensive operation i want to get list of friends only once.

Any pointers ?

Harshit

Comment: You could use a class variable (`@@obj`), but unless you have verified by profiling that this is a performance bottleneck, you should stick with a **before_filter**. Also, Rails has [caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html), which allows you to cache a lot more than your friends list. Also note that in development mode, your controllers are reloaded at every request, so you can only use `@@obj` as a cache

Comment: @Niklas Are you sure that a class variable only lives during the time of one request?

Comment: @NicolasGUILLAUME: yes, I just tested it. Only in development mode, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a before_filter and store the result in cache.

You can also use the session to store the friend list but I would avoid that except if the stored list has a controlled length.

Comment: storing in cache is what i would prefer than session size size is pretty huge.